# Диалоговое окно.Отмена действия

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void LeaveFromField(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    var item = (TabPage)sender;
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(null, "Внимание", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    if (result == DialogResult.No)
    {
       //
    }                
}
```

у `object sender` нет того, что могло бы отменить выход с вкладки,
а в `EventArgs e` кроме стандартных методов для object вообще ничего нет.
Как отменить переход с вкладки?

Answer (score 1):

Решено. Повесил обработчик на сам контрол `Tab` а не на вкладки:

```
private void SelectTab(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)   
{       
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show
    (
        "Выйти?",
        "Внимание",
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
        MessageBoxIcon.Error
    );
    if (result == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        Clear();
    }
}
```